# Creating Command Line Args with gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I have the following code:

> `gcc test.c -o test -D ARGUMENT 2`

and I want it to define ARGUMENT with a value of 2 but it says cannot find file 2 or something. How do I do this?

Comment: One note (wording difference might made it difficult for you) - what you are doing are not "creating command line arguments" - those your program will get at runtime via argc/argv pair of arguments to main(), but you are defining the preprocessor macro with the name "ARGUMENT" to expand to "2". Take a look at the "An introduction to GCC" - http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-GCC-Brian-J-Gough/dp/0954161793/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1256677332&sr=8-1 I personally do not have it, but from the glance at the content it seems nice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

> -DARGUMENT=2

Comment: @bob: it happens even to the best.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc test.c -o test -D ARGUMENT=2`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `gcc test.c -o test -DARGUMENT`.

ARGUMENT will be defined with no value but it is still possible to check it using `#ifdef` and friends.